Height of text field breaks when used inside GridView.count
I render some widgets using SingleChildScrollView and Column. Because the app can run on mutiple dimensions so I want to render the widgets sometimes in pairs like each 2 text fields beside each other and so on.
I tried to use GridView.count like this:
Column(
children: [
     GridView.count(
       crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount, // using mediaquery to get the count
       shrinkWrap: true,
       physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
       crossAxisSpacing: widget.width * 0.006,
       mainAxisSpacing: widget.height * 0.01,
       children: [
       const TextField(),
       const TextField(),
       ],
     ),
  ],
),

the text field itself is ok, but it takes much too much height, and if I pressed on the extra height it focuses on the input field. I tried wrapping it inside a sizedbox, constraintedbox but didn't work. tried using listview and singlechildscrollview and it was the normal behavior, where the text field only took the normal size. I also tried maxLines property and set it to 1 but no luck. What is the problem here?

The problem is the GridView. If you wrap your TextField with a Container & give it a color, you will have the visibility to better understand the space it takes up due to the gridview. You will notice that Gridview widgets are designed to form uniform cell sizes, meaning you cannot force it to change the size of its children independently. To have dynamic size children, I suggest using staggedGridView. Alternatively you may also use Wrap

you mean I should use wrap and include each 2 child in it? that could work, I will try and see if it does @Texv

Using intrinsic height widgets will not help:
You should use the property childAspectRatio within GridView which defines the percent between the mainAxisSize and CrossAxisSize.
it's important to understand how it works:
in your code your representing only 2 TextFields in the cross Axis, which means every text field will allocate the half of screen width.
hence text field width = 0.5 * screen width
when setting aspect ratio to say 2
then, text field height = 0.5 * screen width / 2 .
You got it! aspect ratio by default is 1 which means  height and width both are equal.
GridView.count(

childAspectRatio: 2, // height of each child will be half of its width
....
)


you mean that the solution is to wrap my text fields in AspectRatio and set it as I like? I didn't get the answer

it's safe to say that all the widgets in the GridView are text fields and they all will have the same dimensions.

@OmarYacop, don't wrap by AspectRatio, just use the aspectRatio property , look at the answer again

Now I understand, so you mean that grid view can't handle different children heights because it would even confuse a human being how to handle different heights and put them into a grid view, it won't even be called a grid view at that point, thx
